# Attribute not work more than 2 script

Tags: javascript, html

this is my code:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("formPemasaranSertifikat").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("load").setAttribute("style","");
    document.getElementById("bodi").style.display="none";
<script>
<div class="bodi">
    <?php
        include "menuPemasaranSertifikat.php";
    ?>
</div>

<div id="load" style="display:none;">
    <img src="src/loading.gif" alt="proses upload" />
</div>

<form action="hasilUploadSertifikat.php" method="POST" id="formPemasaranSertifikat" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()"></form>
```

when submit my form, form hidden and div with id load is showing. but the third id not work. id name bodi used to show menu in my page.

if i change line between id load and bodi, it give the opposite.

any suggest?

Comment: Your `bodi` is class not id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `bodi` is class not an id. Try following code

```
<script>
   document.getElementById("formPemasaranSertifikat").style.display="none";
   document.getElementById("load").setAttribute("style","");
   document.getElementById("bodi").style.display="none";
<script>
<div id="bodi">
    <?php
        include "menuPemasaranSertifikat.php";
    ?>
</div>

<div id="load" style="display:none;">
    <img src="src/loading.gif" alt="proses upload" />
</div>

<form action="hasilUploadSertifikat.php" method="POST" id="formPemasaranSertifikat" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(){
    document.getElementById("formPemasaranSertifikat").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("load").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("bodi").style.display="none";
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .hidden{
        display:none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="bodi">
    <?php
        include "menuPemasaranSertifikat.php";
    ?>
</div>
<div class="hidden" id="load">
    <img src="src/loading.gif" alt="proses upload" />
</div>

<form action="hasilUploadSertifikat.php" method="POST" id="formPemasaranSertifikat" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="test()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```